# Fade in/Fade out navigation bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fade

I'm trying to set my navigation bar to remain fixed and fade to 0.8 opacity when i scroll down and return to his normal position and opacity when i scroll back up.

my jquery code is :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    var navOffset = jQuery("nav").offset().top;

    jQuery(window).scroll(function(){

        var scrollPos = jQuery(window).scrollTop();

        if(scrollPos > navOffset) {
            jQuery("nav").addClass("fixed");
            jQuery("nav").fadeTo(1500,0.5);
        } else {
            jQuery("nav").removeClass("fixed");
            jQuery("nav").fadeTo(1500,1);

        }
    });
});
```

and my css code is :

```
.fixed {

    position:fixed;

    top:0;
}
```

It fades out when i scroll down but doesnt return to his original opacity when i scroll back up.I'm new to jQuery.

Comment: Well if you want it to go to `0.8`, for a start I'd change that `0.5` to `0.8`, that solves one problem.

Comment: Yes you are right. I copied the wrong value there .

Comment: This works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/uwhqhjpg/

Comment: Oh now i see ,but why do i have to wait so long to come back up?

Comment: What do you mean to come back up?

Comment: I mean at the opacity of 1 .It takes up to 4 secconds to come back to that opacity .

Comment: Because you've set it go back to 1 opacity after 1.5 seconds (`1500ms`)

Comment: With your code,  getting back up/down depends on the amount of scrolling you do. The more you scroll, it will take longer to show up. Perhaps, may not be the desired behavior you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're setting the `fadeTo` function on every firing of the `scroll` event. Thus, when you scroll down, you're adding many "fade out" calls to the animation effects queue. When you scroll back up, all of the "fade out" effects (each of which takes 1.5 seconds) have to finish before the first "fade in" call takes place.

You can fix this by adding a call to jQuery's `.stop(true)` so that each scroll event clears the animation queue:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  var navOffset = jQuery("nav").offset().top;

  jQuery(window).scroll(function() {

    var scrollPos = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
    jQuery("nav").stop(true);

    if (scrollPos > navOffset) {
      jQuery("nav").addClass("fixed");
      jQuery("nav").fadeTo(1500, 0.5);

    } else {
      jQuery("nav").removeClass("fixed");
      jQuery("nav").fadeTo(1500, 1.0);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 4096px;
  padding-top: 32px;
}
nav {
  height: 128px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #00aa00;
}
.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>so</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">

</head>

<body>

  <nav></nav>

</body>

</html>
```

Note that this means the `fadeTo` animation won't take place until the user stops scrolling.

Comment: Thank you so much ,i've been thinking how to solve that all day .

Comment: You're welcome. The problem becomes a bit harder if you want to start the "fade out" as soon as `scrollPos > navOffset`, but also gracefully handle the case where the user scrolls back to the top before the animation is finished. You can cook something up by looking at the `nav` element's effects queue with `jQuery("nav").queue()`, and keeping track of the currently running animation, perhaps by passing a callback function to `fadeTo`, e.g.  `jQuery("nav").fadeTo(1500, 0.5, function() { // something to do if/when fadeTo finishes }`

Comment: I still have to experiment and learn with jQuery ,but thank you alot for the help,you solved a big problem for me !

Answer (score 0):

It's there another solution to do that? Because when i scroll back up the time that it takes for the "fadeTo" action is verry delayed(~4 secconds) i dont think that's normal.