# Navigationbar with a color that fades out when you scroll down

Tags: javascript, php, css

i have a Q, i have an assignment and im ONLY allowed to use php, css and javascrip.  im really new in java script. but my question is how do i make a navigationbar that has a a color that fades out when u scroll down , i want it to be a one page site. Ps. i am NOT allowed to use Jquery

Comment: Please review the questions guidelines on Stack Overflow here - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask First share what you have tried and then tell us where you are facing issues. We can't write your code for you!

Comment: i'm tryin to make this. with this code. but it has to be without jquery. im only allowed to use javascript. 

 hhttps://codepen.io/willpaige/pen/zeqHd

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fade in/Fade out navigation bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31748265/fade-in-fade-out-navigation-bar)

Comment: im not allowed to use jquery

Answer (score 1):

You can use the JQuery library to solve this problem, it gives you the possibility to do several dynamic things with some server side language.

Here is an example of scrolling with fade of some div, i found it looking on the google for you:

HTML:

```
<div id="container">

<div>Hello</div>
<div>Hello</div>
<div>Hello</div>
<div>Hello</div>
<div>Hello</div>
<div>Hello</div>
<div class="hideme">Fade In</div>
<div class="hideme">Fade In</div>
<div class="hideme">Fade In</div>
<div class="hideme">Fade In</div>
<div class="hideme">Fade In</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container
{
    height:2000px;    
}

#container DIV
{ 
    margin:50px; 
    padding:50px; 
    background-color:lightgreen; 
}

.hideme
{
    opacity:0;
}
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

/* Every time the window is scrolled ... */
$(window).scroll( function(){

    /* Check the location of each desired element */
    $('.hideme').each( function(i){

        var bottom_of_object = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
        var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

        /* If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it it */
        if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ){

            $(this).animate({'opacity':'1'},500);

        }

    }); 

});
});
```

[here the link for example](https://jsfiddle.net/tcloninger/e5qaD/)

Comment: I'm not allowed to use Jquery

Comment: You could use something like: window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);

Comment: You could use in a button with a tag onlick for example.

Comment: yeah i'm only allowed to use javascript, but im pretty new in javascript that's why im asking in here if there is an easy code i can learn

Comment: window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight) => this gonna scroll to the bottom of page, this is a start to you

Comment: i dont know how to use that :S i think i have to search about it